# Which GPU (client or host) is used when running a game through RDP?

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop, gaming, minecraft

I have a **terminal** and a **server**.

The server is running a game client (lets say Minecraft)

My **terminal** is **RDP**ing my **server** and im playing a game on it.

**Who's GPU would minecraft be using?**

Answer (score 3):

In short, **GPU of server is being used** 
See [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/533351-remote-desktop-and-graphics-cards)
Solution to your query from the above link:

> All processing power (including that of the graphics card) is on the host computer. The power from the client computer doesn't matter as long as it has strength enough to run an RDP program...

In the answer given above, just to clarify, "host" is your **server** and "client" is your **terminal** 
Hope this helps!

Comment: What about ICA?